# jqxhr to local server can't find php file

Tags: php, ajax, target, jqxhr

I have updated this question as per Cimbali's suggestion. This is now the js code that specifies the request:

```
......  
function editFiltName($thisFiltCell)    {
  var cellText=$thisFiltCell.text();
  var idx=$thisFiltCell.index(); //alert("idx: idx");
  var newFN=prompt("Enter new filter name below - up to 12 characters.", cellText); 
    switch (newFN)  {
        case    null        : return;   // cancel key hit
        case    cellText    : return;  // no change
        case    ""          : ; //$thisFCell.text('Filter' + (idx+1));
        default             : $thisFiltCell.text(newFN);    
    }   
    var action='updateFiltName';
    var request = MrAjax(action,newFN,idx);
} // end main function
//*******************************************
function MrAjax(action,P1,P2)  { 
    console.log("Ajax-> action: "+action+" P1: "+P1+" P2: "+P2);
    var jqxhr=$.ajax({  
        type: "POST",
        url: "../phpMain/editTblField.php",
        data: {action:action, P1:P1, P2:P2}
    });
    jqxhr.always(function() { console.log("jqxhr.status: " + jqxhr.status ); });
} // end MrAjax
```

This is now the console output when I enter some data:

[image]

Any suggestions? Note that console error is followed immediately by a 'success' response for the same file. But the php file still does not run. I get no php error response from the server - nor do I see my embedded echo I placed on the 1st line of the php file `echo("Got here!);`. That's true even when I comment out everything but that line.

I don't think it's in the php code but just in case, here it is:

```
<?php
echo "Got here!";
?>
```

Thanks again for taking a look.

Comment: Are you sure "finished loading" means a success ? Not just that loading stops since a 404 reply was received ?

Comment: I think you are correct. Good find. When I purposely put a bogus file path into the req I get the same console output. 

OTOH "finish loading" POST data to a file means to me that it found the file and "finished" loading the data to it. Why else would they include the file/path in the message? I've been studying ajax for a couple of years now and using it successfully pretty much. But it seems I still have a way to go to master it. I guess I can stop looking for that hidden 2nd request :)

Comment: And if you copy/paste the exact URL of that message in your browser, you can load the page ?

Comment: @Cimbali I'm away from my dev system and somehow my current files did not make it into my dropbox so I can't test this. I should be back by tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from a typo in your console log, you mixed up concatenations from different languages.

Instead of `console.log("jqxhr.status: " . jqxhr.status );` you want `console.log("jqxhr.status: " + jqxhr.status );`

A second error seems to be that the `status` field doesn't exist (from your comment). However, from the jquery doc, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR :

> The jQuery XMLHttpRequest (jqXHR) object returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 is a superset of the browser's native XMLHttpRequest object. For example, it contains responseText and responseXML properties, as well as a getResponseHeader() method. When the transport mechanism is something other than XMLHttpRequest (for example, a script tag for a JSONP request) the jqXHR object simulates native XHR functionality where possible.
>
> [...]
>
> For backward compatibility with XMLHttpRequest, a jqXHR object will expose the following properties and methods:
>
> ```
> readyState
> status
> statusText
> responseXML and/or responseText when the underlying request responded with xml and/or text, respectively
> setRequestHeader(name, value) which departs from the standard by replacing the old value with the new one rather than concatenating the new value to the old one
> getAllResponseHeaders()
> getResponseHeader()
> statusCode()
> abort()
> ```

I also ready it is a Deferred object, so maybe this strange behaviour comes from trying to access the status field before it exists. Try waiting for the completion of the request.

So instead of `console.log("jqxhr.status: " + jqxhr.status );`, use the following :

```
jqxhr.always(function() { console.log("jqxhr.status: " + jqxhr.status ); });
```

or

```
jqxhr.always(function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log("jqxhr.status=" + jqxhr.status + " : " + textStatus ); });
```

Comment: You caught that console.log error. Thanks. After correcting, the console log has now output the message: 'jqxhr.status: undefined'. I've checked the php file location many times and can find no problem. I have working code in other projects that use the exact same file specification:  url: "../phpMain/editTblField.php",The file shows up in Win explorer and my filezilla as shown. Also, the last line of console output seems to indicate that the file was successfully loaded.

Comment: What version of jquery are you using ?

Comment: So, I guess I have 2 puzzles here. 1) Why does the jqxhr make another request after logging the 1st as a failure to locate the file? And 2) if the 2nd request worked why doesn't the php file run? I just tried it again after commenting out everything in the php file except the echo "Got here!" line. Still no joy.

Comment: What you suggest seems to make sense. I tried both examples. After 1) the console's log output is: "jqxhr status: 404". After 2) it outputs "jqxhr status:404 : error". The other console lines are the same as shown in the question. Good suggestions though. I'm trying to see if somehow I have 2 slightly different requests embedded in my code somehow.

Comment: At least you don't get 'undefined' anymore, which is a good start. You probably should update your question so we can get to the real problem, and see past the typos etc.

Comment: I just took out the request.done js code which is not relevant - to simplify things further.